# Time difference between 2 dates in minutes in R ,it gives wrong results

Tags: r

I have 2 dates:

```
date1 = as.POSIXct("2017-04-12 17:10:59 GMT")
date2 = as.POSIXct("2017-04-12 01:56:00 GMT")
diff = difftime(date1,date2,units = "mins")
```

Output:

```
Time difference of 914.9833 mins
```

(actual o/p : 195 mins)

Comment: What is the problem? Date 1 is like 15 hours and 15 minutes earlier than date 2. 15 hrs * 60 minutes + 15 minutes = 915 minutes

Comment: I think you are confusing `as.POSIXct("2017-04-12 01:56:00 GMT")` as `13:56`.

Comment: I am getting difference of  914.9833 minutes, Which is correct. I am using R version 3.3.2.

Comment: @RonakShah.. I think am confused, now i got it..